# Change alpha of image cropped with SDL_Rect using C++ & SDL

Tags: c++, sdl

I need to adjust the alpha of an image ( SDL_Surface* ) that's been cropped and blitted to the screen using SDL_Rect. I have one image file (.bmp) with 3 images on it, I've cropped each image using SDL_Rect but I need to adjust the alpha of each image individually.
Can this be done?

Failing that, can I store each cropped SDL_Surface* to a new SDL_Surface where i can apply SDL_SetAlpha to each one? 
I realise I could just crop the original image and import them separately, but it's not an option in this case.

I hope that all makes sense, I'm a noob to asking questions on here so forgive me if I've gone against protocol in any way.

Edit:

Here's what i have;

```
SDL_Rect cropBoxPump1 = { 5, 103, 200, 200 };   
SDL_Rect positionPump1 = { 30, 103, 0, 0 };
SDL_Surface* pumpkinConvertedTo32bit = NULL;    
SDL_Surface *pumpkins = SDL_LoadBMP( "pumpkins_faces.bmp" );

pumpkinConvertedTo32bit = SDL_DisplayFormat( pumpkins );        
SDL_BlitSurface(pumpkinConvertedTo32bit, &cropBoxPump1, screen, &positionPump1);
```

So based on that can i actually change the alpha of just the section of the image that's been cropped with the SDL_Rect? and not the whole SDL_Surface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust each surface's alpha individually, it won't affect any of the other surfaces. The only condition is, the surface should have an alpha channel. To check is has an alpha channel, do this:

```
SDL_Surface *surface; // Assume this has been allocated elsewhere.

if (surface->format->Amask != 0)
{
   // You have an alpha channel
}
else
{
   // Make a copy to a surface with an alpha channel.
}
```

Otherwise, then yes, you will have to copy the image to a new surface with an alpha channel. Does that answer your question?

[EDIT]
Here is how you can copy portions of the surface into another one. This is based partially on the documentation [here](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_BlitSurface).

```
SDL_Rect cropBox = { 5, 103, 200, 200 };
SDL_Rect position = {0,0,0,0};
Uint32 rmask, gmask, bmask, amask;

/* SDL interprets each pixel as a 32-bit number, so our masks must depend
   on the endianness (byte order) of the machine */
#if SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN
rmask = 0xff000000;
gmask = 0x00ff0000;
bmask = 0x0000ff00;
amask = 0x000000ff;
#else
rmask = 0x000000ff;
gmask = 0x0000ff00;
bmask = 0x00ff0000;
amask = 0xff000000;
#endif
SDL_Surface *newSurface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_SWSURFACE,cropBox.w,
                             cropBox.h,32,rmask,gmask,bmask,amask);

SDL_BlitSurface(pumpkins,cropBox,newSurface,position);
```

So yeah, create a surface of the right size with an alpha channel, then blit to it.

Comment: Seeing as your surface doesn't have an alpha channel, I would recommend putting each sub-section in a seperate surface. If it absolutely has to stay in a single surface, then you can break into the surface's pixel data an edit it manualy, I can update my post which will show you how to do it, but breaking the image up into seperate surfaces is easier and safer.

Comment: Hi, i just edited my post to show you what i have. if editing the cropped section isnt possible can you show me how to save the cropped section as another Surface? i cant find an example anywhere. thanks heaps for your help

Comment: Wow, that looks pretty heavy! Ok I'll give it a go and let you know the result. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: It's not as complicated as it looks. It just takes into account byte order,(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Take away all the mask stuff, and basically you create a new surface, then blit to it.

Comment: Yeah, fair enuff. I'll definitely let you know how it goes and check it as an answer once i get it working. Thanks again

Comment: ok, been at this all arvo, no good. I think i've got a grip on the createSurface method (roughly) but all i can do with it is create an empty chunk of surface that's only visible if i drop the amask to total zero (not 01, aa, only 00) then it's black. any other ideas? have you actually got it to copy a section of another image?

Comment: Ok, got it. i wasn't using the createSurface method properly. it works b-e-a-utifully!! Thanks so much for your help.